# tikz node rotation and positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, tikz-node

If I specify `/tikz/rotate=<degree>` in some path other than node, it means rotating the coordinate system by `<degree>`.

Consider following example:

`rotate` option inside a node seems to mean rotating the node around its center. But when I combine `rotate` option with a placement option, it confuses me how does the rotation work?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  base/.style={
    minimum height=5mm, minimum width=15mm, draw, rotate=#1
  },
  A/.style={base=#1},
  B/.style={below=1cm, base=#1,},
  C/.style={right=1cm, base=#1,}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill (0, 0) circle (1pt) node [A={0}] {} node [A={90}] {} node[right] {A};
  \fill (0, -1) circle (1pt) node [B={0}] {} node [B={90}] {} node[right] {B};
  \fill (1, 0) circle (1pt) node [C={0}] {} node [C={90}] {} node[right] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The placement options are actually changing the anchor (and possibly adding a shift). They can be looked up in `tikz.code.tex`,

```
\tikzoption{left}[]{\def\tikz@anchor{east}\tikz@possibly@transform{x}{-}{#1}}%
\tikzoption{right}[]{\def\tikz@anchor{west}\tikz@possibly@transform{x}{}{#1}}%
\tikzoption{above}[]{\def\tikz@anchor{south}\tikz@possibly@transform{y}{}{#1}}%
\tikzoption{below}[]{\def\tikz@anchor{north}\tikz@possibly@transform{y}{-}{#1}}%
```

This simply means that you get rotations about that anchor. I marked these anchors by dots to illustrate the point.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  base/.style={
    minimum height=5mm, minimum width=15mm, draw, rotate=#1
  },
  A/.style={base=#1},
  B/.style={below=1cm,label={[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,anchor=center]north:{}},base=#1,},
  C/.style={right=1cm,label={[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,anchor=center]west:{}}, base=#1,}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill (0, 0) circle (1pt) node [A={0},red] {} node [A={90},blue] {} node[right] {A};
  \fill (0, -1) circle (1pt) node [B={0},red] {} node [B={90},blue] {} node[right] {B};
  \fill (1, 0) circle (1pt) node [C={0},red] {} node [C={90},blue] {} node[right] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the anchor has the location specified by `below=1cm` or `right=1cm`, and then the shape gets rotated about that anchor.